# Excel's Range.Value property no longer works with xlRangeValueMSPersistXML parameter after update

Tags: excel, vba

After a recent windows/office update, Excel's Range.Value property does not seem to work when passed the xlRangeValueMSPersistXML parameter, which tells the range's Value property to return range data in XML format.  Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

here's my code (credit to https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/)

```
    Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML) <- this fails now
    adoRecordset.Open xlXML
```

Comment: Exactly how does it fail? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Thanks for your note.  The error message is, "Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed'".  When i use the xlRangeValueDefault or xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet parameters, the method works, but of course it returns the wrong format.  It's only the XML datatype that seems no longer to be working.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly true that Range.value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML) does not work any more.

After the update xlRangeValueMSPersistXML works differently.
In particular it is data sensitive to the numeric cells values.

It assumes that numeric cells values are a sort of integer; if they are double it fails.
There are no issues with text cells. I tried it with only one cell, and it works based on the value contained.

In facts now it creates such XML:

for a text cell:

```
    <xml xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
 xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"
 xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
 <x:PivotCache>
  <x:CacheIndex>1</x:CacheIndex>
  <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
   <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
    <s:attribute type="Col1"/>
    <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
   </s:ElementType>
   <s:AttributeType name="Col1" rs:name="Field1">
    <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
   </s:AttributeType>
  </s:Schema>
  <rs:data>
   <z:row Col1="A TEST"/>
  </rs:data>
 </x:PivotCache>
</xml>
```

and for numeric

```
    <xml xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
 xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"
 xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
 <x:PivotCache>
  <x:CacheIndex>1</x:CacheIndex>
  <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
   <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
    <s:attribute type="Col1"/>
    <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
   </s:ElementType>
   <s:AttributeType name="Col1" rs:name="Field1">
    <s:datatype dt:type="int"/> <---- The culprit!!! It was dt:type="Number" before...
   </s:AttributeType>
  </s:Schema>
  <rs:data>
   <z:row Col1="460251"/>
  </rs:data>
 </x:PivotCache>
</xml>
```

The change is that now it uses `<s:datatype dt:type="int"/>` while before the update it used `<s:datatype dt:type="Numeric"/>`

Probably int does not means exactly 0-32768. I noticed that it failed with cells of bigger value (e.g. 2206484). So probably after the update, we will need to define the XML data structure prior to load XML data. At the moment I do not have idea how to do that, but probably we will need a kind of trick like *numberformat* or something else.
Moreover, after several error messaging testing the values in cells I got:

**Run-time error: '-2147417848 (80010108)
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its client**

and I was not any more to get the XML vales from cells I was reading few seconds before.

I think we are near a workaround.

Comment: I have just received the Excel update 1906 - Build 11727.20244 Click-to-run.
I tried with either string and numbers and **it works now**!

It uses  **int** or **float** for numbers, and **dt:maxLength="255"** for text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I have the same line of code and get the runtime error: "Error number -2147417848, Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed. This happened right after the latest Excel update.

I haven't found a code workaround but did manage to solve the problem by rolling back to the previous release.

Fixing some typos in a CNET post managed to roll back.

Open an elevated command window and change to the directory:

`cd %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun
officec2rclient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.11425.20244`

That is the last version for the monthly release channel of office 365. You can find versions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fae942449-1fca-4484-898b-a933ea23def7

In Excel you need to go to `File->Account->Update Options` and turn off updates. Not optimal but better than rewriting my code until a fix is in.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I am not the only one experiencing this problem.  Over the past 24 hours, I've implemented a non-ideal workaround that avoids the use of recordsets altogether.  Microsoft has a mammoth task, trying to update and improve Windows/Office without disrupting decades of functionality;  i don't envy them this task.  I do hope they can resolve this problem, however, in a near-future release.

Comment: I've messaged the Excel team on Twitter and sent them some info. They suggested leaving feedback in Excel with the error to help escalate the issue which I did.

Answer (score 0):

For those that either dont want to roll back office or are unable to do so, I have started on a workaround. It will use the previous method if it works, so it will only actually run the workaround on those machines that have the issue.

If filtering is not needed you can just create your own recordset and add each column with the type adVariant from the ADODB DataTypeEnum.

If you need filtering (as I do) then the workaround is below. This should be considered a work in progress as I have only tested the functionality I use, and it doesn't implement all datatypes. Use it at your own discretion.

You will need references to ADO and to RegEx (Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5). Also to Microsoft XML, but if you replace the 2 references with the type Object it should also be fine.

The XML section first attempts to read using the previously working range.value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML) method, and only uses the workaround if that fails. In the XML section, there is also a fix for a bug with the XML method where it reads 2 cells for a column name if the top of the range is not on row 1.

The workaround is fixed to using the top row as headers. It reads in the data and attempts to determine the datatype from each column. It then uses that datatype to populate the recordset and return it.

```
    Public Function RSFromRange_XML(rngInput As Range) As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim xlXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Dim xmlRange As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim h As String
        Dim varArr() As Variant
        Dim MatchPattern As String
        Dim reg As RegExp
        Dim matches As MatchCollection
        Dim m As Match
        Dim lngMaxLen As Long
        Dim lngMaxLenIndex As Long

        Set reg = New RegExp
        reg.IgnoreCase = False
        reg.MultiLine = True
        reg.Global = False

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        Set xlXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

        On Error Resume Next
        xmlRange = rngInput.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set rs = rsFromVarArr(rngInput)
            rs.MoveFirst
            GoTo ExitSuccess
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        varArr = rngInput.rows(1).Value

        'we ignore the column fixup when the range starts at the top of the sheet
        If rngInput.rows(1).row <> 1 Then
            For i = LBound(varArr, 2) To UBound(varArr, 2)
                'our lovely unadulterated header
                h = varArr(1, i)

                'Matches the recordset header name, our real header name, and all the garbage in between.
                MatchPattern = "rs:name=[""][^""]*" & h & "[""]"
                reg.Pattern = MatchPattern

                If reg.test(xmlRange) Then
                    xmlRange = reg.Replace(xmlRange, "rs:name=""" & h & """")
                End If
            Next i
        End If

        xlXML.LoadXML xmlRange
        rs.Open xlXML

    ExitSuccess:
        Set RSFromRange_XML = rs
    End Function


    ' This is a workaround for a bug in excel, so consider it a work in progress.
    ' It may fail in some situations, if it does, those will need to be handled.
    Public Function rsFromVarArr(rngInput As Range) As Recordset
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim data() As Variant
        Dim header() As Variant
        Dim varArr() As Variant
        Dim arrFieldTypes() As ADODB.DataTypeEnum
        Dim arrDefinedSize() As Long
        Dim h As Variant 'ADO field workaround
        Dim record() As Variant
        Dim r As Variant 'ADO record workaround

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        'read data into var arr
        data = rngInput.Value

        'headers
        header = rngInput.rows(1).Value
        ReDim header(LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2))
        For i = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
            header(i) = data(LBound(data, 1), i)
        Next i

        'check header col count matches data col count
        'Debug.Assert (UBound(header) - LBound(header)) = (UBound(data, 2) - LBound(data, 2))


        ' Date -> DateTime -> String -> variant
        ' Integer -> single -> double -> String -> variant
        ' boolean -> string -> variant

        ' Work out the variable types
        ReDim arrFieldTypes(LBound(header) To UBound(header))
        ReDim arrDefinedSize(LBound(header) To UBound(header))
        For i = LBound(arrFieldTypes) To UBound(arrFieldTypes)
            For j = LBound(data, 1) + 1 To UBound(data, 1)
                arrFieldTypes(i) = getCompatibleADOType(data(j, i), arrFieldTypes(i))
                If arrDefinedSize(i) < LenB(data(j, i)) Then arrDefinedSize(i) = LenB(data(j, i)) + 2
            Next j
        Next i

        'Now fix variable types
        For i = LBound(arrFieldTypes) To UBound(arrFieldTypes)
            For j = LBound(data, 1) + 1 To UBound(data, 1)
                If IsEmpty(data(j, i)) Or data(j, i) = "" Then
                    'data(j, i) = Null
                    data(j, i) = Empty
                Else
                    Select Case arrFieldTypes(i)
                        Case adBoolean: data(j, i) = CBool(data(j, i))
                        Case adUnsignedInt: data(j, i) = CByte(data(j, i))
                        Case adInteger: data(j, i) = CLng(data(j, i))
                        Case adDecimal: data(j, i) = CDec(data(j, i))
                        Case adSingle: data(j, i) = CSng(data(j, i))
                        Case adDouble: data(j, i) = CDbl(data(j, i))
                        Case adDate: data(j, i) = CDate(data(j, i))
                        Case adVarChar: data(j, i) = CStr(data(j, i))
                        Case adVarWChar: data(j, i) = CStr(data(j, i))
                        Case adVariant: data(j, i) = data(j, i)
                        Case Else
                            Debug.Assert False 'we shouldnt get here
                    End Select
                End If
                'arrFieldTypes(i) = getCompatibleADOType(data(j, i), arrFieldTypes(i))
                'If arrDefinedSize(i) < LenB(data(j, i)) Then arrDefinedSize(i) = LenB(data(j, i)) + 2
            Next j
        Next i

        'add all headers to the rs
        For i = LBound(header) To UBound(header)

            If arrFieldTypes(i) >= 200 And arrFieldTypes(i) <= 203 Then
                If arrDefinedSize(i) = 0 Then arrDefinedSize(i) = 20
                rs.Fields.append CStr(header(i)), arrFieldTypes(i), arrDefinedSize(i)
            ElseIf arrFieldTypes(i) = adEmpty Then
                rs.Fields.append CStr(header(i)), adVariant, 20
            Else
                rs.Fields.append CStr(header(i)), arrFieldTypes(i)
            End If

            If arrFieldTypes(i) = adDecimal Then
                rs.Fields(header(i)).NumericScale = 14
                rs.Fields(header(i)).Precision = 4
            End If
        Next i
        rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        rs.LockType = adLockPessimistic
        rs.Open

        ' ADO requires this, as it can read from a variant containing an array,
        ' but not from an array of variants!
        h = header
        ReDim record(LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2))

        'Read  data 1 record at a time
        'assuming the top row is header info
        For i = LBound(data, 1) + 1 To UBound(data, 1)
            For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
                record(j) = data(i, j)
            Next j
            r = record


            rs.AddNew h, r
        Next i

        Set rsFromVarArr = rs
    End Function


    ' If no ado type is supplied, this will return the closest match to vbVar
    ' If AdoType is supplied, this will find an ado type that is compatible with both the
    ' adoType and the vbVar
    Private Function getCompatibleADOType(ByVal vbVar As Variant, Optional AdoType As ADODB.DataTypeEnum) As ADODB.DataTypeEnum
        Dim ret As ADODB.DataTypeEnum
        ' These ado types are not handled
        If AdoType = adBSTR Then AdoType = 0
        If AdoType = adEmpty Then AdoType = 0
        If AdoType = adError Then AdoType = 0
        If AdoType = adGUID Then AdoType = 0
        If AdoType = adGUID Then AdoType = 0
        If AdoType = adIDispatch Then AdoType = 0

        If AdoType = adIUnknown Then AdoType = 0
        If AdoType = adPropVariant Then AdoType = 0
        If AdoType = adUserDefined Then AdoType = 0

        'Excel promotes some types, demote them where possible.
        'we dont want ints reading as doubles, or bools reading as ints
        If IsEmpty(vbVar) Then
            ret = AdoType
            getCompatibleADOType = ret
            Exit Function
        ElseIf IsNumeric(vbVar) Then
            If vbVar = CLng(vbVar) Then
                If vbVar = 0 Or vbVar = -1 Or vbVar = 1 Then
                    vbVar = CBool(vbVar)
                Else
                    vbVar = CLng(vbVar)
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbString And (UCase(vbVar) = "TRUE" Or UCase(vbVar) = "FALSE") Then
            vbVar = CBool(vbVar)
        End If

        ' Boolean -> Integer -> Decimal -> String -> Variant
        ' Date -> String -> Variant
        ' Integer -> Decimal -> Double -> String -> Variant
        ' Single -> Double

        Select Case AdoType
            Case adBoolean
                If VarType(vbVar) = vbEmpty Then
                    ret = adBoolean
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbBoolean Then
                    ret = adBoolean
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbByte Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbInteger Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbLong Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbDecimal Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbCurrency Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbLong Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbLong Then
                    ret = adInteger

                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbSingle Then
                    ret = adDouble
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbDouble Then
                    ret = adDouble
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbString And (UCase(vbVar) = "TRUE" Or UCase(vbVar) = "FALSE") Then
                    ret = adBoolean
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbString Then
                    ret = adVarWChar
                Else
                    ret = adVariant
                End If

            Case adDate
                If VarType(vbVar) = vbEmpty Then
                    ret = adDate
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbDate Then
                    ret = adDate
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbDouble Then
                    ret = adDate
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbString Then
                    ret = adVarWChar
                Else
                    ret = adVariant
                End If

            Case adUnsignedTinyInt, adSmallInt, adInteger
                If VarType(vbVar) = vbEmpty Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbBoolean Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbByte Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbInteger Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbLong Then
                    ret = adInteger
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbSingle Or VarType(vbVar) = vbDouble Then
                    If vbVar = CLng(vbVar) Then
                        ret = adInteger
                    Else
                        ret = adDouble
                    End If
                Else
                    ret = adVarWChar
                End If

            Case adBigInt
                If VarType(vbVar) = vbEmpty Then
                    ret = adBigInt
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbBoolean Then
                    ret = adBigInt
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbInteger Then
                    ret = adBigInt
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbLong Then
                    ret = adBigInt
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbSingle Or VarType(vbVar) = vbDouble Then
                    If vbVar = CLng(vbVar) Then
                        ret = adBigInt
                    Else
                        ret = adDouble
                    End If
                Else
                    ret = adVarWChar
                End If

            Case adNumeric, adDecimal, adCurrency
                If VarType(vbVar) = vbEmpty Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbBoolean Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbCurrency Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbDecimal Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbInteger Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbLong Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbSingle Or VarType(vbVar) = vbDouble Then
                    If vbVar = CLng(vbVar) Then
                        ret = adDecimal
                    Else
                        ret = adDecimal
                    End If
                Else
                    ret = adVarWChar
                End If

            Case adSingle, adDouble
                If VarType(vbVar) = vbBoolean Then
                    ret = adDouble
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbCurrency Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbDecimal Then
                    ret = adDecimal
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbInteger Then
                    ret = adDouble
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbLong Then
                    ret = adDouble
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbSingle Or VarType(vbVar) = vbDouble Then
                    If vbVar = CLng(vbVar) Then
                        ret = adDouble
                    Else
                        ret = adDouble
                    End If
                Else
                    ret = adVariant
                End If

            Case adVarWChar 
                If VarType(vbVar) = vbEmpty Then
                    ret = adVarWChar
                ElseIf VarType(vbVar) = vbString Then
                    ret = adVarWChar
                ElseIf Not IsError(CStr(vbVar)) Then
                    ret = adVarWChar
                Else
                    ret = adVariant
                End If

            Case adVariant
                ret = adVariant
            'unimplemented types
            'Case adBinary: 'raw data
            'Case adLongVarBinary 'long raw
            'Case adVarBinary 'raw data
            'Case adDBTimeStamp
            'Case adChar
            'Case adVarChar
            'Case adWChar
            'Case adLongVarWChar

            Case Else
                'ret = adVariant
                '===============================
                Select Case VarType(vbVar)
                    Case vbBoolean 'adBoolean
                        ret = adBoolean
                    Case vbByte 'adInteger
                        ret = adInteger
                    Case vbInteger: 'adInteger
                        ret = adInteger
                    Case vbLong: 'adInteger
                        ret = adInteger
                    Case vbDecimal 'adDecimal
                        ret = adDecimal
                    Case vbCurrency 'adDecimal
                        ret = adDecimal
                    Case vbSingle 'adSingle
                        ret = adSingle
                    Case vbDouble 'adDouble
                        ret = adDouble

                    Case vbDate 'adDate
                        ret = adDate
                        'ret = adDBTimeStamp
                    Case vbString 'adVarWChar
                        ret = adVarWChar

                    Case vbError 'adError
                        ret = adEmpty
                    'Case vbVariant 'adVariant
                    '    ret = adVariant
                    Case vbEmpty ' Null equiv
                        ret = adEmpty
                    Case vbNull ' Null equiv
                        ret = adEmpty
                    Case vbObject
                        ret = adIDispatch
                    Case vbDataObject
                        ret = adIUnknown
                    Case vbArray 'We dont want to be getting here
                        Debug.Assert False
                        ret = adArray

                    Case Else
                        ret = adVariant
                End Select
                '===============================
        End Select

        If ret = 0 Then ret = adEmpty
        getCompatibleADOType = ret
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

see below my workaround for this issue as a function that returns a recordset based on a specified input range. I replaced the old XML method in my code with this and the resulting recordset seems to have the same functionality, ie it supports filtering and sorting.

Hope this helps!

```
Function rng2ADOR(rng As Range) As ADODB.Recordset

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    Dim sConnection As String
    Dim sSQL As String

    sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & rng.Worksheet.Parent.FullName & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & rng.Worksheet.Name & "$" & rng.Address(False, False) & "]"

    Set rng2ADOR = New ADODB.Recordset

    'allow local ador cursor to be used independently to source
    rng2ADOR.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    'open static & read-only ADOR
    rng2ADOR.Open sSQL, sConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

End Function
```